# While loop skipping every other input

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that will open a user input file name and then take the names in that file and arrange them from LastName, FirstName MiddleName to FirstName MiddleName LastName. However I my while loop is skipping every other name in the input file.

Here is my main:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string fullName;
    string lastName;
    string first_middleName;

    size_t pos;


    string fileName;
    ifstream inData;

    cout << "Please type the file name including extension(such as .txt)." << endl;
    cout << "If your file is in a different directory please specify the path:";

    getline(cin, fileName);
    inData.open(fileName.c_str());

    if(!inData) {
        cout << "Cannot open" << fileName << "." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    getline(inData, fullName);

    while(getline(inData, fullName)) {
        pos = fullName.find(',');
        lastName = fullName.substr(0, pos);
        first_middleName = fullName.substr(pos + 2);
        cout << first_middleName << " " << lastName << endl;
        getline(inData, fullName);
    }


    inData.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seams like you need to get acquainted with a debugger. If you're on a linux based system, I'd recommend GDB...

Answer (score 5):

This is because you read two lines per loop

```
while(getline(inData,fullName)){
    ...
    getline(inData,fullName);       
}
```